# Four vertices of a regular dodecagon are midpoints of the sides of a square of area $24$. Find the area of the dodecagon.

Tags: geometry

A  regular polygon with 12  sides (dodecagon) is inscribed in a square of area 24 square units as shown in the figure where four of the vertices are mid points of the sides of the square . The area of the dodecagon in square units is?

[image]

Comment: you are encouraged to include your attempt as well.

Comment: i get ans 18 but the ans should be 19.26

Comment: since you have done it, try to include your working as well? others might be able to tell what went wrong and you get to learn more. Also, who knows, perhaps you are right and people get to check for you.

Comment: $18$ is the correct answer if $4$ vertices are placed at mid-point of the sides of the square. The $12(2-\sqrt{3})\sqrt{6}^2 \approx 19.2\color{red}{9}$ number corresponds to four edges of the dodecagon is lying on the square. Is you figure correct?

Comment: @achillehui The answer `19.29` is correct and was asked in `TCS aptitude round`. Can you explain it more?

Answer (score 1):

This fairly-well-known dissection of the dodecagon shows it to have three-quarters the area of the surrounding square.

[image]

In the current case, the area becomes $\frac34\cdot 24 = 18$. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

One formula for the area of a regular polygon is:
$$area=\frac{r^2 n  \sin(\frac{360}{n})}{2}$$ 
where $r$ is the circumradius and $n$ is the number of sides of the polygon. For $r$ we have half the length of a side of the square: $${(2r)}^2=24 \rightarrow r=\frac{\sqrt{24}}{2}=\frac{2\sqrt{6}}{2}=\sqrt{6}$$ So area would then be (for 12 sides):
$$area=\frac{{\sqrt{6}}^2*12*\sin(\frac{360}{12})}{2}=\frac{72 \sin(30)}{2}=18$$